# Arm strength for cricket

Tags: strength, arms

What exercises can I do to help me bowl faster?

Comment: Due to specificity of training I bet there are specific answers to this question. eg [this article on pitching](http://www.stack.com/a/how-to-increase-pitching-velocity) states that you can't transfer lower body strength to your throw unless you train the muscles that keep your shoulder from flying out of its socket. Maybe sports.stackexchange.com would know better?

Comment: @Noumenon - Sports would likely reject it and pass it along this way anyway, most requests for workouts get kicked from there. This is just a very broad "throw spaghetti" type of question. As one of the CM's tends to say "Don't migrate crap".

Answer (score 2):

Your weight training should involve anything that increases your overall strength and musculature of the arms and supportive muscles used in bowling, and that can be incrementally loaded.

So as an assumption, stuff that targets the back, shoulder capsule, core, posterior chain etc.

I'd suggest focusing on squats, deadlifts, and overhead press all using a barbell. Aim to become decently strong on these exercises relative to your bodyweight.

Comment: I would include explosive exercises like power cleans in that suggestion. OP seems to want rapid activation of muscles.